# java conundrum pertinent to lists

Tags: java, list, indexing

I find myself to be troubled by this unresolved(as of yet) conundrum. . Let's say we have a list of integers l and this list contains objects in the following order : 1,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6 with the first element i.e. 1 having the index 0 and the last element i.e. 6 having the index 8.. now every time I use l.indexOf(2), the value returned is 1, how do I access the indexes of the other 2s without removing anything from the list?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to iterate through the list, and compare each item in it to your target value, and keep track of the locations where you find it.

In fact, if you look at the [implementation of `ArrayList#indexOf()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) that's effectively what it's doing, except that it's only returning the first match:

```
/**
 * Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element
 * in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.
 * More formally, returns the lowest index <tt>i</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>,
 * or -1 if there is no such index.
 */
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Your real decision is how you want to store off the found locations.  For instance, you could stick them in another `List` like so:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6});
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    int i=0;
    for (int value : list) {
        if (value == 2) {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(indexes); // [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a List might be the wrong data structure for your needs. Maybe a MultiSet would work.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html